# r : how to make tribble with IDate

Tags: r

Would you like to tell me how to fix my code?
I want column D.LasrPV and D.LastCEMI as IDate, but below code give me errors..

```
tribble(
    ~SUBJID, ~D.LastPV,  ~D.LastCEMI,
    2610041, as.IDate('2022/05/23'), as.IDate('09/05/2022'),
    2618012, as.IDate('2022/09/02'), as.IDate('09/02/2022'),
    2641012, as.IDate('2022/07/25'), as.IDate('08/29/2022'))
```

Error gives me:
Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: At the very least tell us the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing your reprex line by line:

```
> as.IDate('2022/05/23')
[1] "2022-05-23"
>   as.IDate('09/05/2022')
[1] "0009-05-20"
> as.IDate('2022/09/02')
[1] "2022-09-02"
>   as.IDate('09/02/2022')
[1] "0009-02-20"
> as.IDate('2022/07/25')
[1] "2022-07-25"
>   as.IDate('08/29/2022')
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

`as.IDate()` doesn't seem to be doing what you want.

Fix by specifying the date formats:

```
testframe <-  tribble(
    ~SUBJID, ~D.LastPV,  ~D.LastCEMI,
    2610041, '2022/05/23', '09/05/2022',
    2618012, '2022/09/02', '09/02/2022',
    2641012, '2022/07/25', '08/29/2022')

testframe %>% mutate(
  D.LastPV = as.IDate(D.LastPV, "%Y/%m/%d"),
  D.LastCEMI = as.IDate(D.LastCEMI, "%m/%d/%Y")
)
```

gives:

```
># A tibble: 3 × 3
   SUBJID D.LastPV   D.LastCEMI
    <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1 2610041 2022-05-23 2022-09-05
2 2618012 2022-09-02 2022-09-02
3 2641012 2022-07-25 2022-08-29
```